# How to tell LaTeX to automatically split text and its equation (and multi-equations) across pages?

Tags: amsmath, page-breaking, split, layout, vertical-spacing

Managing the vertical spacements, LaTeX frequently displaces an equation and the text line above it to the next page.  This behavior may leave a large blank space on the previous page (depending on the preamble settings).  I want to prevent these blank spaces *without having variable vertical spaces* between text lines or text and equations.  So I want LaTeX to keep a text line to the bottom of a page, and push the next equation to the second page (without its text line right above it).

As an option, the text line and its equation may take the bottom space reserved for the footnotes, if there is no footnote there.

Also, I would like LaTeX to automatically split multi-equations across the pages, only for the align and gather environments.

How can I do that?  Here's a MWE code to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom % Without this option, vertical spacings may be ugly... 
\usepackage{microtype}
% To reduce hyphenations:
\pretolerance=5000
\tolerance=9000
\emergencystretch=0pt
\righthyphenmin=4
\lefthyphenmin=4
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

% Space around equations:
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

\chapter{Some chapter title}

\blindtext[1]:
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation}
\blindtext[1]:
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation}
A few words of text and an equation:
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation}
A few words of text and an equation:
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation}
A few words of text and an equation:
    \begin{align}
        E &= m c^2, \\
        E &= \hbar \omega.
    \end{align}
A few words of text and an equation:
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have the `\allowdisplaybreaks` directive.

Comment: Does this command also allows a split of a text line and its equation below it ?

Comment: I think these are independent problems.

Comment: Do you mean that I should ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Not necessarily. The code you've posted has no special problem for me.  What's not like what you want? Note that `\allowdisplaybreaks` is for multiline  equations. You only have a single two-line equation in your code.

Comment: The code doesn’t show explicitly the line+equation issue (which is hard to reproduce with a simple MWE code). I also need to make LaTeX to split a text line and the equation below it. Or let them occupying a part of the footnote space, if necessary.

Comment: @Cham it should be easy to make an example of whatever issue you want (just force the paragraph above to have as many lines as you need `a\\a\\a\\a` for example, to force the page break at the bad place you ask about. It is very hard to understand currently. To allow extra space on pages without footnotes you can not easily automate but in any particular case you can use `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` or however much extra space you want to allow.

Comment: @David Carlisle, that last code you gave is interesting. I suggest you present it as an answer (with Bernard’s command).

Answer (score 2):

`amsmath` has an `\allowdisplaybreaks` command to allow multi-line displays to split over a page.

To allow extra space on pages without footnotes you can not easily automate but in any particular case you can use

```
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
```

or however much extra space you want to allow.

Comment: Could you give an explicit example about how to use these commands?